# C# Sending buttonclicks to same Object

Tags: c#

I have a lot of buttons in my project. To make the program I shorter need to get every click of a button to the same "Button_click" method. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes this is possible. Just subscribe the same method to all their click events.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to use one click event handler for multiple buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315936/c-how-to-use-one-click-event-handler-for-multiple-buttons)

Comment: Now i'm stuck in an inf loop. Thanks Cody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it's perfectly possible.

You don't say whether you're WinForms or WPF but the basic way is to create a private method that's the handler and then call that from each button handler:

```
private void ButtonHandler(some arguments)
{
}

private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonHandler(some arguments);
}
```

However, you can just subscribe the same handler to each button's click event:

```
Button1.Click += ButtonHandler;
Button2.Click += ButtonHandler;
```

Or set these from the designer - just pick the existing method from the drop-down list rather than creating a new handler.

With WPF you can quite easily bind each button click to the same handler in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Click="ButtonHandler" ... />
<Button x:Name="Button2" Click="ButtonHandler" ... />
```

Again the designer gives you the choice of selecting an existing handler as well as creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! if i would like to send an integer with this specific button to the method, and do this to all of my buttons, Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Kneed - have the arguments as `int value` and then call with `ButtonHandler(10)` or some expression that evaluates to an integer

Answer (score 5):

Just use the same event handler for all the buttons. In code, this would be:

```
button1.Click += HandleButtonClick;
button2.Click += HandleButtonClick;
```

etc

It should be possible to do in the designer too.

If these are buttons in different forms, you'll need to either have a *static* handler method somewhere, or each form will need a reference to whatever class has the handler method. You may well need to add these handlers in code, rather than using the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, just select the method you need in your **Events** tab of Properties Window designer (you can show it from the main menu: View -> Properties Window):

[image: events tab]

Or do it manually in `<Formname>.Designer.cs` file:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
//...
this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Also, if you want to perform slightly different actions depenging of which button was pressed and still only use one  method, use `sender` argument. Its value will always be a reference to the button that was clicked, so you can do some logic by looking at button's `Name` or `Tag` properties:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    switch((int)btn.Tag) {
        case 1:
             // action 1
             break;
        case 2:
             // action 2
             break;
    }
}
```

Still, you should be careful with this and see if it really gives you any benefits to share an event handler instead of creating separate handlers for different buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! where do i find the events tab?