# C# How to use one click event handler for multiple buttons

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Sending buttonclicks to same Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315737/c-sending-buttonclicks-to-same-object)

I have a lot of buttons in my project. To make the program I shorter have made every click of a button to the same "Button_click" method by editing the Designer.cs file and pointing every click to my method.

```
 this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Mymethod);
```

How can I identify which button that has been pressed in the Mymethod method?

Thanks!

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315737/c-sending-buttonclicks-to-same-object

Comment: Unless I am much mistaken, you should take the () off this.MyMethod.  It looks like you are invoking Mymethod and passing the return value of Mymethod into the EventHandler (which won't work).

Answer (score 9):

MyMethod must be declared this way:

```
void Mymethod (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (sender == btn1)
      MessageBox.Show ("Button1");
}
```

Use the sender argument.  This is your button (the object that raised the event).

Answer (score 6):

The click handler is usually structured like this:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In this, what you're looking for is `object sender`.  That will be a reference to the control which sent the click event.  It's boxed as an `object` but if you know the type (in your case you say they're all buttons) then you can cast it:

```
var myButton = (Button)sender;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find that a much cleaner approach to this problem is to set the CommandName and CommandArgument of each button and instead of using OnClick use a shared OnCommand handler.

That handler will accept a CommandEventArgs parameter instead of an EventArgs parameter, and you'll be able to interrogate it directly to see the CommandName and CommandArgument of the button clicked.

Answer (score 1):

set tag property of all buttons that wanna  to have same click handle to a number like  1

and call this in form constructor to set all buttons click event handler

```
 public void SetButtonClick(Control parent)
    {
        if (parent is Button)
        {
                (parent as Button).Click += new EventHandler(this.Mymethod);
        }
        foreach (Control item in parent.Controls)
        {
            SetButtonClick(item);
        }
    }
```

for checking which button pressed check button Tag