# How Do I Link Multiple Buttons With Their Corresponding Labels While Using A Timer? (Visual Studios 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, timer, label

I got an answer from a previous problem but it isn't quite right. I want `button1` to do the same thing as `button2` but, it isn't. I also want to know how I should add more buttons to the code (I need 4 buttons in total). I don't know if there is an easier way to achieve the same results as to what I am trying to do. if there is, please explain it to me. I have been struggling with c# (Or I think they call it Windows I'm not quite sure) because, I am relatively new to it. I am trying to learn how to fix my code but, this answer is not what I familiar to. I usually use `Button btn = (Button)sender;` with `tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);`. Here is the answer I got (I edited it a bit so that might be where I went wrong).

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SerCorrespondingButtons();
        this.SetCorrespondingInitialButtonInscriptions();
    }
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private Dictionary<Button, Label> correspondingControls;
    private Dictionary<Button, string> initialButtonInscriptions;

    private List<string> sayingsList;
    private Button currentButton;

    private int i;
    private void SerCorrespondingButtons()
    {
        correspondingControls = new Dictionary<Button, Label>()
                                                              {
        {this.button1, this.label1},
        {this.button2, this.label2},
                                                              };
    }

    private void SetCorrespondingInitialButtonInscriptions()
    {
        this.initialButtonInscriptions = new Dictionary<Button, string>()
                                                              {
        {this.button1, this.button1.Text},
        {this.button2, this.button2.Text}
                                                              };
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (this.currentButton != null)
        {
            this.currentButton.Enabled = true;
            this.currentButton.Text = this.initialButtonInscriptions[this.currentButton];
            this.currentButton.Click += this.button2_Click;
            tmr.Enabled = false;
            tmr.Tick -= timer2_Tick;
        }
        this.currentButton = button;
        var saying = this.correspondingControls[button];
        saying.Visible = true;
        button.Text = "Click To Hide Saying";
        button.Click -= button2_Click;
        button.Click += button2_Click2;
    }
    private void button2_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var saying = this.correspondingControls[button];
        saying.Visible = true;
        if (saying.Visible)
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
            saying.Visible = false;
            button.Text = "Reactivating in 5 seconds";
            tmr.Interval = 1000;
            button.Click -= button2_Click2;
            button.Click += button2_Click;
            this.i = 4;
            tmr.Tick += timer2_Tick;
            tmr.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            this.currentButton.Text = "Reactivating in " + i + " seconds";
            i -= 1;
        }
    }
```

It didn't come with notes so, if you can put notes/comments in your answer that would be very appreciated. And if you can also give me links as to what I should look up I would really appreciate it! As I said, I tried other methods but, they haven't came close to this way. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Does Anyone Have Any Answers To This Problem?

Answer (score 0):

a `Button_click` is an event , in c# event are made to notify objects about any modification or something that happened to a specific object .

the button is an object that has alot of events  same as Click
so if you want your buttons to do the same event you can just listen to them all and make ONE `FUNCTION/OPERATION` for them all 
you can refer to this link 
[C# How to use one click event handler for multiple buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315936/c-sharp-how-to-use-one-click-event-handler-for-multiple-buttons)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this implies to the code. Keep In mind that I didn't make the code I just adjusted it. Some of the code isn't very familiar with me

Comment: what i understand from your question is how can all of your buttons do the same function or the same action

Comment: That is the question but, I also asked what was wrong with Button 1. I know how to make the buttons do the same function if I did the code myself. I didn't do this and have no idea as to why it's not working completely.