# C# Possible to use single EventHandler<EventArgs> for thousands of objects?

Tags: c#

I have a collection with thousands of nodes. I'd like each node to fire a Changed() event to notify the container.

Normally, registering an event creates a new EventHandler<>:

```
Node node = new Node();
node.Changed += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnChanged);
```

This would result in thousands of EventHandler<> objects.

I'd like to know if it is possible to construct a single EventHandler<> and use it simultaneously with thousands of nodes:

```
class Container {
    EventHandler<EventArgs> eventHandler = 
      new EventHandler<EventArgs>(OnChanged);

  void CreateNode() {
    Node node = new Node();
    node.Changed += eventHandler;
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI-- The Changed() event is to notify the container that a re-sort may be needed. Imagine a SortedSet<> with an Item setter in addition to Add/Remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can: Reference the `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` as described on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Here is a sample class that notifies when it's properties are changed:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string firstName
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this.firstName; }
        set 
        {
            if( this.firstName == value )
            {
                return;
            }

            this.firstName = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");

        }
    } 

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       if( this.PropertyChanged != null )
       {
           this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
    }
}
```

Then use the `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>` because it fires the following events:

```
`CollectionChanged` - Occurs when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed

`PropertyChanged` - Also an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged inteface, which fires when the collection's own properties change.
```

Comment: Hot damm! MSDN: "For change notification to occur in a binding between a bound client and a data source, your bound type should either: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (preferred)." **How did you know I am trying to bind client nodes to a data source!!?**

Comment: @Kevin R I work with this in Silverlight and WPF. It seemed to me that your issue was very similar to what I work with.

Comment: This looks great! Any ideas how it compares to a regular event? Resources/speed? Wondering if there is any advantage to doing a bit more reading to implement this vs plain vanilla event.

Comment: For simple collections this is not an issue. However, if you you have life time objects that fire the `PropertyChanged` event you should use `System.Windows.WeakEventManager` because it handles the event routing/subscription and between components more efficiently. This is recommended because whenever you subscribe to an event of an object, you must unsubscribe from that event or else the subscriber runs the risk of leaking (memory leaks)... I think for your purpose the performance should be fine as the collection itself only subscribes to events of its children..

Comment: "the collection itself only subscribes to events of its children" YES. Do I really have to unsubscribe (implement IDisposable)? I suppose a client could hold on to a node beyond the container's lifetime, so that's probably a 'yes'. Darn.

Comment: No you don't. The unsubscribe is handled automatically as you add and remove objects to the collection. You also do not need to implement IDisposable either. It is good out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. What you have done should work fine. Is it not working for you?

Comment: If appropriate, it would seem to be a MASSIVE savings in instantiations. Added: I haven't tried it yet, not because I don't think it will work, but I wanted opinions/experience if this is defective and going to blow up in production.

Comment: yes, you can also create your own eventargs and pass in some other identifier if you need to. Or just get the sender node and do your logic.

Comment: Right. Just need the notification (so far). Wanted a bit of input before committing. :)

Comment: its just a delegate which is a pointer to the method. Behind the scenes the compiler will create a new instance for every node.

Comment: I read that happens when you provide the method directly as in: `node.Event += Handler()` which is just syntactic sugar for `+= new EventHandler<>()` -- but in this case I would be providing a reference to an EventHandler<>(). Still think a new instance will be created for each? **Seems crazy to have thousands of EventHandler<> objects all pointing to the same place!**

Comment: Trust me, you will be fine. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315737/c-sending-buttonclicks-to-same-object.