# C# checkbox checked count

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, count

I have several checkboxes and a button inside a panel, that is inside a tabPage, inside a WinForm C# application.

What I am trying to do is making sure at least one checkbox is checked so enable the button to be clickable, if not the button will be disabled (gray display non-clickable).

I tried this (in `Form_Load` event) but it didn't work:

```
int counter = 0;
        foreach (Control p in tabPage1.Controls)
        {
            if (p is Panel)
            {
                foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is CheckBox)
                    {
                        if (((CheckBox)c).Checked)
                        {
                            counter++;
                        }
                        if (counter < 1)
                        {
                            button1.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button1.Enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It's either because I am using the wrong event or the wrong place to put the code, or the code itself isn't correct, can anyone take a look please?

Comment: Why not use [CheckedListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) instead? Then it's as simple as getting `CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this (note.. your specific loops are redundant.. you know the name of the container.. why loop searching for it?)

```
if (panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(x => x.Checked)) {
    // at least one is checked..
```

Comment: in what event should i put that one dear sir ?

Comment: `CheckChanged` event of the checkboxes. Make all of your checkboxes use the same `CheckChanged` event handler.. that way you only need to put this into that one event.

Comment: is there anyway i can avoid to input the code in all checkboxes ? like to just put something somewhere to count how many check boxes are checked ?

Comment: Yes. You make all of your checkboxes use the same `CheckChanged` event. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315737/c-sharp-sending-buttonclicks-to-same-object for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be run in two places:

- The form's `Load` event, after you've loaded the checkboxes with any saved values
- The checkboxes' `CheckedChanged` event handlers, so the button state is updated as checkboxes are checked

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part
you never use "p" variable in your code below...

```js
foreach(Control p in tabPage1.Controls)
{
  if (p is Panel)
  {
```

```js
int counter = 0;
foreach(Control c in panel1.Controls)
{
  if (c is CheckBox)
  {
    if (((CheckBox)c).Checked)
    {
      counter++;
    }
    if (counter < 1) {
      button1.Enabled = false;
    }
    else {
      button1.Enabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```